# Are there any reasons why one should use MPI's Wtime?

Tags: mpi

I've been wondering whether there are any particular reasons why one should use Wtime instead of other time measurement methods? Is it more accurate or reliable?

The only reason I see is platform independence.

Comment: Platform independence of timing measurement is a surprisingly non-trivial advantage.

Comment: I fully agree. I'm not underestimating it. It's the only reason I'm aware of at the moment, so was wondering whether it has even more advantages. I'm not sure of this, but another one would be to use it with a global clock which is present in some implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Since MPI_Wtime() guarantees that the beginning time at all ranks is the same, it can not only be used for calculating time between any two points at the same rank, but also to compare the the time taken by different ranks to reach a certain point very conveniently.

There can be other applications too for this globally synched clock, but right now i can think only about this.

Answer (score 0):

MPI_Wtime() does not guarantee the global synchronization among process lying on different nodes. It does provide the synchronous clock for process lying on same node but also gettimeofday() provides the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual for MPI_Wtime (Open MPI 4.0.0):

> On  POSIX  platforms, this function may utilize a timer that is cheaper to invoke than the gettimeofday() system call, but  will  fall  back  to  gettimeofday()  if  a  cheap  high-resolution  timer is not available.  The ompi_info command can be consulted to see if Open MPI supports a native high-resolution timer on your platform; see the value for "MPI_WTIME support"  (or  "options:mpi-wtime"  when  viewing  the parsable output).  If this value is "native", a method that is likely to be cheaper than gettimeofday() will be used to obtain the time when MPI_Wtime is invoked.